# Getting my table to make new rows instead of into cells

Tags: javascript, arrays, datatables, rows

```js
document.writeln("<tr>");
for(i=0; i < arrayName.length; i++)
{
    document.writeln("<td>" + (arrayName[i]) + "</td>");
}
document.writeln("</tr>");
```

I currently have this however I'm aware this is creating more cells rather than rows so the inputs of the array are coming up horizontally. I want to make it so each input will create a new row rather than cell.

I've tried a few different ways but can't seem to get the correct way to do it.

Comment: Move the two statements which write `<tr>` and `</tr>` to inside the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

A table row is defined by the `<tr>` tag, while a table cell is define by the `<td>` tag.

If you want each element in the array to show in its own row in the table, you need to wrap each element in both `<tr>` and `<td>` tags.

```
for(i=0; i < arrayName.length; i++)
{
    document.writeln("<tr> <td>" + arrayName[i] + "</td> </tr>");
}
```

Comment: Hi Andr, welcome to SO. Please keep in mind that while this code may solve the problem, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it works would improve the answer's long-term value.